# Vue Autocomplete initialDisplay is not displayed

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js

I am using VueJS with Firebase. I am trying to update data using a form. In the form, I am able to get old data in almost all fields. There is an autocomplete field, in which I am not to display the fetched data. The data is present in initialDisplay but not display. It seems like the object is not fetched.

Here is my code

```js
    <CustomerAutoComplete
       description="Select customer associated with this project"
       label="Customer"
       placeholder="Customers"
       @selected="clientSelected"
       :initialValue="projectForm.customerId"
       :initialDisplay="customer"
       v-model="projectForm.customerId"
     />

props: {
    customer: {
      type: Object
    }
  },

data: function () {
    return {
      projectForm: {
        customerId: '',
        address: ''
      } as Project
    }
  },

  methods: {
    clientSelected ({ selectedObject }) {
      this.projectForm.customerId = selectedObject.id

      if (selectedObject.address) this.projectForm.address = selectedObject.address
    },
  },
```

Here is what I can from the browser console in the Vue tab.

```js
{"id":"op234Sd3FBZHwfLpk16n","companyId":"zErEDd6jE4a0H6bY8u77","name":"Test Customer","email":"test@customer.com"}
```

In data section, I can Object but no data.

I feel like I am missing something small, no idea what it is.

Thanks in advance for your help!